# Paste all corresponding even line numbers of two files

Tags: unix, paste

I have two huge files with this format (fastq):
file 1:

```
@f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:1 length=20
NTCCANAAAAGCAGTGGTAT
+f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:1 length=20
#AAAA#FF<FFFFFFFAF<F
@f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:2 length=20
NACAANCACCCAGGGGAGAG
+f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:2 length=20
#7AAA#FFFFFAFFFF<<FF
```

file 2:

```
@f.2 A:B:C:D:E:F:1 length=60
NCGTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+f.2 A:B:C:D:E:F:1 length=60
#.A..F######################################################
@f.2 A:B:C:D:E:F:2 length=60
NGCCTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+f.2 A:B:C:D:E:F:2 length=60
#<AAA<######################################################
```

I'd like to paste every even line number (lines 2,4,6,..) from file 1 with every corresponding even line number from file 2. 
The odd line numbers can be left with that of file 2 (I'll subsequently change the length value to reflect the updated length, which is 80 in the case of this example.)

So my result file will be:

```
    @f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:1 length=80
 NTCCANAAAAGCAGTGGTATNCGTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    +f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:1 length=80
 #AAAA#FF<FFFFFFFAF<F#.A..F######################################################
    @f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:2 length=80
 NACAANCACCCAGGGGAGAGNGCCTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    +f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:2 length=80
 #7AAA#FFFFFAFFFF<<FF#<AAA<######################################################
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `paste` is a good way to go about it. Just paste all the lines, then correct the odd ones. Based on your example, my correction here is a simple `sed`. YMMV if there are other variables at play not shown in your example:

```
$ paste -d '\0' file1 file2 | sed 's/ length=20.*$/ length=80/g'
@f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:1 length=80
NTCCANAAAAGCAGTGGTATNCGTTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:1 length=80
#AAAA#FF<FFFFFFFAF<F#.A..F######################################################
@f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:2 length=80
NACAANCACCCAGGGGAGAGNGCCTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+f.1 A:B:C:D:E:F:2 length=80
#7AAA#FFFFFAFFFF<<FF#<AAA<######################################################
```